# how to get get fix this error "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing."

Tags: django

filtering 2 models

```
id = request.GET.get('StudentID')
studentenroll = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(Student_Users=id)
payment=StudentsPaymentSchedule.objects.filter(Students_Enrollment_Records=studentenroll)
return render(request, 'Homepage/enrollmentrecords.html',{"studentenroll":studentenroll,"payment":payment})
```

my models

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Discount_Type = models.ForeignKey(Discount, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Remarks = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Student_Users}  {0.Education_Levels}'
        return suser.format(self)
class StudentsPaymentSchedule(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records=models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Payment_Schedule = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Amount = models.FloatField()
    Remarks=models.TextField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Students_Enrollment_Records}'
        return suser.format(self)
```

can you guys help me for my assignment, cause i dont know how to connect this 2 models in views and i am little confuse in filtering . thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `__in` operator; Because `studentenroll` is a queryset, not a single object.

`payment=StudentsPaymentSchedule.objects.filter(Students_Enrollment_Records__in=studentenroll)`

Also, work a bit on your var/class/atrs naming; [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Your alternate won't work because OP renamed his `related_name`s to `+`.

Comment: Good catch; Thanks for the heads up. Not sure why he'd to that. Probably by mistake :)